# SVN to Git tags in weird location

Tags: git, svn, migration, git-svn

I have a couple of my projects on a SVN server. But when I started with the SVN server I had no clue about how a SVN setup should be.

So my current SVN repo layout is like this:

```
https://mysvn/svn
    trunk
        project1
        project2
    tags
        project1-tag1
        project1-tag2
        project2-tag1
        project2-tag2
```

After some thought I decided to go to Git, and followed the SVN to Git tutorial of Atlassian, and I am able to define my custom trunk layout, but my tags are a problem.

I can use the command

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk/project1/ --authors-file=authors.txt https://mysvn/svn/ Project1AsGit
```

But how do I incorporate the tags without having the tags of project2 inside of project1?

Answer (score 0):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

You will be able to setup the rules file so that you end up with two Git repositories where stuff is exactly where you want it and named like you want it and all with one run of the tool. You can even rename the tags in the process from `project1-tag1` to `tag1` and so on in the process.

Comment: I've looked at the KDE one, but that looks way to complex and the server I am using does not have enough disk space. Because from what I've read it will make a local copy of the SVN db. So I want to use this one: https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git So is it correct that I need to use the following command? `svn2git https://mysvn/svn --trunk /trunk/project1 --nobranches --tag /tags/project1*` ?

Comment: That `svn2git` is based on `git-svn` and so not well suited for a one-time conversion. Also the space on the server is not too relevant. Just copy the repository files to your local machine and run `svn2git` there, it also will be a gazillion faster. And even if you run `svn2git` on the server, it will not copy the repository files, but just create the Git repository out of it. So if you have enough space for the Git repository it will be enough. What the correct command for `git-svn` is, I cannot tell you, as I try not to use it where I can. ;-)

Comment: Your answer made me think about another solution. I actually have a bunch of projects, and most of the tags of those projects are in their dedicated folder, I only have 3 projects that have it like that. What I ended up doing is just using `git-svn`, but ignoring the tags. 

Then in SourceTree, I went through the log and manually created a tag everywhere maven added the release log. This was manual, but way easier and faster than setting up a complex system to do it automatically.